# Sabre request error

Tags: sabre

I have got "Error in Request: No Pax types given" from the response of Bargin Finder Max API and here is my request:

[image]

I use json.dumps to turn the dictionary into json.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the passenger type to the request like the way it's shown in the sample docs?

"AirTravelerAvail" : [ {
        "PassengerTypeQuantity" : [ {
          "Code" : "ADT",
          "Quantity" : 5,
          "Changeable" : true
        } ]
      } ],

I would use just one ADT to test.

Comment: They are requesting 1 (SeatsRequested: [1]), but you have 5, (Quantity: 5)